# How do I use the socks module in Python to download a webpage?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, socks

http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/

```
>>> import socks
>>> s = socks.socksocket()
>>> s.setproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,"socks.example.com")
>>> s.connect(("www.example.com",80))
>>>
```

After I connect to the proxy, how do I download a webpage?

Note: I do not want to use "setdefaultproxy". I already have working code for this method.

```
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxy_ip, proxy_port)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(3)
    my_ip = urllib2.urlopen('http://whatthehellismyip.com/?ipraw').read()
```

I want to use the "connect" method.

Comment: Sinse you are not willing to use a lib to handle HTTP requests I guess you will have to build one manually. In essence it is actually quite simple, but you may have trouble coding it to support keep-alive sessions, compressed server responses and HTTPS addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit here as I haven't used that socksipy module but...

you probably need to send a header first

```
s.send('GET / HTTP 1.1 / Host: localhost');
```

or some such.. "" might even work.

and then read the buffer from socket as in:

```
resp = s.recv(4096);

while (len(resp) > 0):
    print(resp);
    resp = s.recv(4096);
```